# Why is the Shem Havaya pronounced as the Shem Adnut?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names

I was wondering why, after the true pronunciation of the Shem Havaya was lost, was it decided that the name be pronounced like the Shem Adnut - and not like any other one of Hashem's names? Why was the Shem Adnut chosen?

Comment: Heavily overlaps with https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97936/ and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71413/, and seems to be an exact duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65378/

Comment: The question here is why the shem Adnut is used rather than some other pronounciation. The answers there do not answer this particular question. @DonielF

Comment: @sabba Would not the source for pronouncing י-ה-ו-ה as א-ד-נ-י suffice as answering why we pronounce it that way? The answer is, it was chosen because Hashem said we should in Shemos 3:15 as interpreted in Pesachim 50b and elsewhere.