# Printing a once-off siddur that would require genizah

Tags: prayer-book, shemos-sacred-names, genizah-storage

I have been asked to compile a booklet containing the Shacharit service for a special occasion. The printed booklets (currently 60 pages long, double-sided 2-per-page, so 15 pieces of paper each) will probably never be used after the occasion and would have to be put in sheimos. I would like to modify the relevant names and words in the text to avoid this.

1. Is printing single-use siddurim that would need to be put in sheimos a bad idea, possibly because it is disrespectful to the holiness of the siddur, or maybe just wasteful?
2. Is removing the holy names an inappropriate / disrespectful thing to do to a siddur?
3. After modification, would the booklet possibly *still* be required to be put in sheimos simply because of its nature as a siddur?

Please supply your sources or reasoning for your answers.

Comment: I have seen such booklets and they indeed replaced the name of Hashem to avoid the issue you mention. You might find the [OpenSiddur](https://opensiddur.org/) project relevant and useful (not an endorsement!) - they call themselves *the open-source community project for folk sharing prayers and crafting their own prayerbooks*

Comment: [similar](/q/14913/170)

Comment: There were thousands of _siddurim_ printed, although not exclusively, with two _yuds._ Why would it mean a problem?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56866/explicit-shaimos-printed-in-prayer-books